# Running wget with PHP and apache (MAMP)

Tags: php, apache, wget, macports

I have trouble running wget through php exec or system functions. The configuration is with MAMP.

I successfully run basic commands like ('whoami', 'pwd', etc.).

I even changed the apache user to the root user and still nothing. In the error log it output "wget: command not found".

I can run with the terminal and it works fine. The wget is installed through Macports.

What should I do?

Regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a terminal, run `which wget`, and use the full path in the call to exec/system.